# How could I retrieve and store random UUID-s in ZeroMQ sockets?

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I need to communicate between multiple clients. When I try to run file (multiple terminals) I get same identity. So I let router socket to automatically set the UUID. But what I found I cannot use that identity to store at server for routing between multiple clients.

How would I handle multiple clients IDs?

I am trying to build an asynchronous Chat server. I am following an approach of each client with dealer socket connects to server ( **`ROUTER`**-type sockets ). Server then extract the clients IDs ( set manually ) and reads the message and route accordingly.

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(void) {
    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::socket_t backend (context, ZMQ_DEALER);
    backend.setsockopt( ZMQ_IDENTITY, "mal2", 4);
    backend.connect("tcp://localhost:5559");

    std::string input;
    std::cout <<"you are joinning" << std::endl;

    while(1){
        getline (std::cin, input);
        s_send (backend, input);
        zmq::pollitem_t items [] = {
            { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
        };
        zmq::poll (items, 1, -1);
        if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            std::string identity = s_recv (backend);
            std::string request = s_recv (backend);//receive reply back from router which might be other client
            std::cout<<"identity="<<identity<<"reques="<<request<<std::endl;
        }   //ending if                               
    }//ending while
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Memento

It has been proved by decades to rather design a system based on all collected requirements, i.e. before coding, not vice versa.

This way your analysis will list **all** the requirements before deciding on messaging and signalling layer, avoiding situations "And also I want to add this and that ..."

### UUID

If you decide to create a disposable or persistent **`UUID`**-s on each client side, you face a challenge to ensure both temporal uniqueness & randomisation.

If you decide to assign **`UUID`**-s from a ChatSERVER side, you need an additional signalling layer, besides the chat-transport.

Answer to "How would I handle multiple clients ID" is not answer-able without the other requirements you are sure to have ( or will sooner or later realise to face 'em, on-the-fly )

### Time is money

As said above, good projects start with proper and thorough **requirements engineering** & validation. The product coding than spans a minimum amount of time, compared to a "Aha-based & trouble-shooting responsive engineering".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I am trying to build a client chat server using multithreading. I am doing it for learning purpose.Clients need to communicate with each other but clients chat would be visible to all.

Comment: i though i would need a router to receive messages and another router to redirect messages. But i cant retrieve the UUIDS

Comment: How did you decide to technically generate the **UUID**?

Comment: s_set_id(dealersocket or req socket). It set the identity as 64F6 D716. So every client has same identity thats the problem i could not identify multiple clients to carry out my intended solution .I am open to your suggestions

Comment: http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter3#Identities-and-Addresses i am using this kind of examples

Comment: Make it two step, on a first contact, generate UUID for the new client ( a server provided key ) plus if needed, set another authentication element, to avoid man-in-middle / spoofing / faked entities et all. Once the client accepts this, your server can both identify any chat payload and also can review, if the sender is authentic or not. ( If in doubts, read and re-use some lighter crypto-key exchange handshaking / exchange and validation )