# zeromq dealer and router. while taking input from console(using cin) I miss messages from other clients

Tags: c++, sockets, zeromq, polling

I am building a chat server. I have set identities for each socket. when i send a message to server(router). server parse the message and extract the UUID of intended message. Server then send message to client(corresponding to that identity).

I am doing this on client side:

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "datamsg.pb.h"


zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t backend (context, ZMQ_DEALER);

using namespace google::protobuf::io;


static void * worker_thread(void *arg) {
    datamsg p = datamsg();
    p.set_source("cl3");p.set_port(5559);
    std::string input;
    while(1){
    getline (std::cin, input);   //separate thread for asynchronous input
    p.set_messagee(input.substr(3,(input.length()-1)));
    p.set_destination(input.substr(0,3));
    std::string str;
    p.SerializeToString(&str);
    zmq::message_t request (str.size());
    memcpy ((void *) request.data (), str.c_str(),str.size());
    backend.send(request);
 }
}

int main(void) {
   backend.setsockopt( ZMQ_IDENTITY, "cl3", 3);
   backend.connect("tcp://localhost:5559");
   zmq::message_t received_instant_msg;
   datamsg receive_parsed;
   pthread_t worker;
   pthread_create(&worker, NULL, worker_thread, NULL);
          std::cout <<"you are joinning" << std::endl;
while(1){


  zmq::pollitem_t items [] = {
 { backend, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }
 };
 zmq::poll (items, 1, -1);
    if (items [0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
       std::string emptystring = s_recv (backend); //first string is empty ""
       backend.recv(&received_instant_msg); //Now parsing the message down there
       receive_parsed.ParseFromArray(received_instant_msg.data(),   received_instant_msg.size());
// printing the parsed messages here

                }  //ending if
    } //while
return 0;
}
```

I cannot get past cin input to receive message. Once i enter input at console and send it , then i can receive queued messages from server.:(
How would I deal this.? Can multithreading approach be adopted this way? if yes then how?

Comment: You're going to have to provide actual code if you want anyone to have any ideas about what might be wrong with it.

Comment: @Jason I have posted the code, See if you could help me, please do!!!

Comment: @Jason I need to communicate between multiple clients. When i try to run file (multiple terminals) i get same identity. So I let router socket to automatically set the UUID. But what i found I cannot use that identity to store at server for routing between multiple clients. How Would I handle multiple clients ID. I am trying to build an asynchronous Chat server. I am following an approach of each client with dealer socket connects to server(router sockets) . Server then determine multiple clients IDs and reads the message and route accordingly.

Comment: Gotcha.  Not to leave you hanging, I'll take a look next chance I get and see if I can set you on the right path.

Comment: OK, you need to understand your addressing system. How does one client indicate another client with which it wants to communicate? This isn't a ZMQ problem, it's an architecture problem that you'll have to solve for yourself for your particular scenario. Specifically, how does a client identify themselves? You said each client is getting the same identity... when every client says "I'm mal2" (pulling from your script), something smells wrong there. Each client needs a unique identity, and it needs to know the unique identity of the client it wants to talk to.

Comment: @monsterrrrr let me ask, [monsterrrrr], whether you have prepared your Requirement List (as a minimum), before coding a mock-up sample? Seems, that all the help and recommendation from >>> http://stackoverflow.com/a/25910452/3666197 did not help to get you a step farther. Asking for a help is possible, but your professional reflection shall rather demonstrate both your will and your persistence to build on previous questions, not re-iterating the same issue under just another use-case example.

Comment: @Jason. Actually I have mulitple client bwith identities of mal1 and mal4(hardcoded in each files). But infact, when a clients sends an input i encode the destination id (like cl4, cl3) in protocol packet and send it to server. server then parse the packet and retrieve whether the message was intended to cl4,cl3 or cl3. and then send it to that clients. But I have to hardcode each client I am adding. I want to mitigate that thing.I have updated the code for your concern.Thanks

Comment: @Jason SOmeone on the IRC told me to not set the Identities (to keep them randomized). But I cannot access these identities at router to route among multiple clients. these IDs are unprintable and not accessable. Whatever that is!!! Waiting for your reply. Thanks

Comment: You're conflating two different concepts, and I believe @user3666197 is right, you don't fully understand your requirements.  At least, *I* don't fully understand your requirements, and I don't think I can really help unless I do.